# Unable to access the Docker nodejs container on the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

I am using windows ver 10 home, so I am using "docker toolbox for windows" where my docker client is windows/amd64 and server is linux/amd64.

I have built a very simple nodejs application with three files.

server.js

```
/**


* Created by farhanx on 7/28/2018.
 */
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 5000;
const HOST = 'localhost';

// App
const app = express();


app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.get('/students', function (req, res) {

    res.send('student page\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log('Running on http://'+HOST+':'+PORT);
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "First Last <first.last@example.com>",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.1"
  }
}
```

Docker file

```
FROM node:8
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Then I have built my docker image successfully and ran this command

> docker run -p  5001:5000 farhan/mynode

since I have mentioned port 5000 for the server inside the nodejs server file and inside the docker file I have exposed the 5001 as a port.

Now it runs fine and shows on the console that the nodejs server is running but whenever I use localhost:5001, it displays page not found. Which means somehow docker container is working fine but is not accessible to the browser.

Comment: does your app work without docker? i.e. run node app directly

Comment: Yes @Aman B its working fine without docker on localhost:5000.

Comment: You say you're using Docker Toolbox; does http://192.168.99.100:5001 work?

Comment: Thank you David, yes it did work using this ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using toolbox, you have to access app in your browser via http://linux_docker_host_ip:5001.

To know the host ip, go to virtualbox, and see the docker machine's ip address. Normally you will find a network icon on right bottom corner when you click on vm in virtual box. By default the IP is '192.168.99.100'

Answer (score 3):

Exposing a port means you let through request asking for that port. You have to expose the port 5000 and not the 5001.

```
EXPOSE 5000
```

Also, you should not set the HOST of your Express app to `localhost`. If you do this, only localhost (the container) will be able to make request.

Usually, you do not set the host (it defaults to 0.0.0.0 and accepts everything):

```
app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: I followed as you suggested now my docker file and server.js file has same port 5000. I have also removed the localhost. But still after running the docker i am unable to connect. here is my container info $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d8937bf8a0b6        farhan/mynode       "npm start"         2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        5000/tcp            tender_varahamihira

Comment: The result of your `docker ps` command does not show the port mapping. Are you sure added `-p 5001:5000` to your `docker run` command?